# How to rewrite Elm 0.18 Date functions to Elm 0.19

Tags: elm

I am trying to upgrade Elm 0.18 to 0.19 and got stuck on a final step, where I can't figure out how to rewrite Elm 0.18 code to Elm 0.19. One issue I had was that the package `mgold/elm-date-format": "1.5.0 <= v < 2.0.0`, which was one of the dependencies of the project, was not upgrded yet to support Elm 0.19 so I decided to replace it with [ryannhg/date-format](https://github.com/ryannhg/date-format). I've also read in the migration docs that `Time` and `Date` moved to [elm/time](https://github.com/avh4/elm-upgrade) but I can't figure out how to rewrite the code below. I have no idea about Elm whatsoever so please go easy on me, I was just tasked to upgrade Elm from 0.18 to 0.19 in my project. I am trying to learn it, though.

Here's the code I have right now which does not work after upgrading to 0.19 plus the full stacktrace. I used the automated [Elm upgrade tool](https://github.com/avh4/elm-upgrade) for upgrading Elm

Code:

```
module Views.Note exposing (view)

import Data.Note.Author exposing (Author)
import Data.Note exposing (Note)
import Html exposing (Html, text, span, tr, td, p)
import Html.Attributes exposing (class)
import Date.Format exposing(format)
import Date
import Views.Note.Author

-- VIEW --

view : Note -> List Author -> Html msg
view note authors=
  let
    author = List.head (List.filter (hasAuthorId note.authorId) authors)
  in
    case Date.fromString(note.createdAt) of
      Ok date ->
        tr []
          [ td [ class "stacked" ]
            [ span [ class "date" ][ text (format "%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %P" date) ]
            , Views.Note.Author.view author
            , p [ class "text" ][ text note.text ]
            ]
          ]
      Err _ -> text ""

hasAuthorId : Maybe Int -> Author -> Bool
hasAuthorId authorId author =
  case authorId of
    Just authorId ->
      author.id == authorId
    _ ->
      False
```

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/Page/Notes.elm
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/elm-webpack-loader/index.js):
Error: Compiler process exited with error Compilation failed
-- UNKNOWN IMPORT -------------------------------- app/javascript/Views/Note.elm

The Views.Note module has a bad import:

    import Date

I cannot find that module! Is there a typo in the module name?

The "source-directories" field of your elm.json tells me to only look in the
app/javascript directory, but it is not there. Maybe it is in a package that is
not installed yet?


    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/jedrek/workspace/ironin/lease_management_system/node_modules/node-elm-compiler/dist/index.js:131:35)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:588:12)
```

Comment: The old `Date.fromString` was a best-effort implementation that delegated to JavaScript and therefore wasn't very predictable as it tried to parse whatever it got, returning a `Date` object which might or might not be valid. This doesn't fit very well with idiomatic Elm, so it was removed. `ryanhg/date-format` is a package for converting TO a string, not FROM a string, so this won't help you here. You need to know which specific format your date string has and choose a library that's able to parse that format.

Comment: As is, your question does not include enough information to determine which format the string has, and therefore how to parse it. But even if it did, it would basically amount to just asking for a library recommendation, which is unfortunately explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow. You might want to try the [Elm Slack](https://elmlang.herokuapp.com/) or [Elm Discourse](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/) instead, since they're more suitable for providing guidance.

Comment: @jedi do you have enough to go on now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base type for Dates and Times now is `Posix`. That's what the formatter functions will expect. The most direct replacement for `Date.fromString` now is in https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/rtfeldman/elm-iso8601-date-strings/latest/Iso8601 - see the `toTime` function,

You'll need to handle a result rather than a Maybe, and the total size of your compiled package will go up as this uses parsing libraries rather than using javascript's native data parser